I'm curious if there's a step-by-step guide available for transitioning Magento 2 Admin UI to React (not the frontend)
I am trying to use the Magento Admin panel. I want to change UI with ReactJS and keep the all backend functionalities same. Could you point me in the right direction or provide any resources that might be helpful? I can't find any way out!
I recently developed a React admin application with basic components to test data retrieval for the Admin panel. I have encountered CORS issues preventing data access. Despite resolving the CORS issue, the Nginx server fails to start. Mentioning that I have installed Magento using Docker.
